# How Can I Keep My Discord Bot Logged In Without Resorting To Task.Delay?

Tags: c#, task, discord, discord.net

I'm currently running a Discord bot, but it won't stay logged in unless I add `await Task.Delay(-1)` to the method I use to log-in. I'm suspecting this is causing me some issues in later parts of my code.

Here is how I connect:

```
        public override async Task ConnectToClientAsync()
        {
            await this._client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, this.Token);
            await this._client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
```

**How do I keep my bot online without resorting to using `Task.Delay(-1)`?** It just logs in, and once completed successfully it then terminates the program (as it doesn't stay logged in without this delay).

**Main**

```
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var newBot = new WelcomeBot(674094599903641628);
            await newBot.LaunchBot();
        }
    }
```

**WelcomeBot**

```
    public class WelcomeBot : BasicBot, IMessageWriter, IMessageReader
    {

        private ulong _channelId;

        public WelcomeBot(ulong channelId) : base()
        {
            this._client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            this._channelId = channelId;

            ConfigureBotFunctionality();

        }

        private void ConfigureBotFunctionality()
        {
            Interact_UserEntryAndExit();
        }

        private void Interact_UserEntryAndExit()
        {
            this._client.UserJoined += AnnounceUserJoiningAsync;
            this._client.UserLeft += AnnounceUserLeavingAsync;
            this._client.Connected += OnConnectAnnouncementAsync;
        }

        public async Task LaunchBot()
        {
            await ConnectToClientAsync();
        }

        public override async Task ConnectToClientAsync()
        {
            await this._client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, this.Token);
            await this._client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private async Task OnConnectAnnouncementAsync()
        {
            // ..
        }

        private async Task AnnounceUserLeavingAsync(SocketGuildUser leavingUser)
        {
            //..
        }

        private async Task AnnounceUserJoiningAsync(SocketGuildUser joinedUser)
        {
            //..
        }

        // Other functions.
   }
```

Comment: Can you show your main function?

Comment: @John Updated the original post with Main and the WelcomeBot Class

Comment: Try moving the `await Task.Delay(-1);` to main

Comment: @John I added a `while (true) {};` at the bottom. Seems to be working fine.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk - you could consider adding something like a `Console.WriteLine("Bot is running; hit ENTER to exit"); Console.ReadLine();` to main. That will keep the console open without having to run a `while(true) {}` loop.

Comment: @MIchaeJones Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: `I'm suspecting this is causing me some issues in later parts of my code` - what problems exactly? Every option used so far is simply blocking the program from continuing ... busy wait with while, waiting for key press or an infinite delay. Any issues you are having shouldn't be related to the task delay, you probably need to do some further investigations

Answer (score 0):

Just add a small delay, 300 or 400 or something.